# PHP/Codeigniter Recursive Categorization

Tags: php, codeigniter, recursion

Background:

I have a platform that allows users to add / edit categories in a parent > child fashion at an unlimited depth.

Each category has an **ID**, **NAME** and **PARENT**

At the moment, I'm using a recursive query to get the parent "Breadcrumb" trail from any given category. However, that is causing a huge lag time and subsequent crash of my web server.

The solution I came up with was to get all the information first and foremost and then sort through it after all the data has already been pulled.

This is where I am coming to a standstill.

Ultimately, my goal is to have the parent category trail for each category set in a database field alongside the corresponding category.

Example:

**Category D**

Parent: *Category A* > *Category B* > *Category C*

This is what I have so far....

```
private $crumb;
private $sortedArray = array();

public function update_breadcrumb()
{
    $this->sorted_array = array();
    $this->crumb = $this->get_crumb_parent_data();
    //print_r( $crumb );

    $this->get_data_from_array();

    //print_r( $this->crumb );

    foreach ($this->crumb as $cr){

        $parent = $cr['parent'];

        // **This is where I'm getting hung up**

    }

}

private function get_crumb_parent_data( $parent_id = 0 )
{
    $this->db->select('id, name, parent');
    $this->db->from('categories');
    $this->db->order_by( 'parent', 'ASC' );
    //$this->db->where("parent", $parent_id);
    $result = $this->db->get()->result_array();
    return $result;
}

private function get_data_from_array( $parent_id = 0 )
{
    foreach( $this->crumb as $key => $c )
    {
        if ( $c['parent'] == $parent_id )
        {
            $this->sorted_array[$c['id']] = $c['name'];
            unset( $this->crumb[$key] );
        }
    }
}
```